# Logging with PrintStream

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I have class that changes printing from console to file

```
public class LogWriter {
private static PrintStream fileStream;
private File file;
private String id;
private String currentDate;

public LogWriter(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    file = new File(LOGS_DIR + id);
    try {
        currentDate = java.time.LocalDate.now().toString();
        Files.createDirectories(file.getAbsoluteFile().toPath());
        File logPath = new File(file, currentDate + LOG_EXTENSION);
        logPath.createNewFile();
        fileStream = new PrintStream(LOGS_DIR + id + SLASH + currentDate + LOG_EXTENSION);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.setOut(fileStream);
}
```

An my proggram gets http requests, and when http request comes I use log.info to print.

```
@GetMapping(value = SLASH_SIGN + GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getRequest() {
    log.info(GET);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(OK);
}
```

And when it prints to console, everything works well, but when I print to file using PrintStream some strings print on each other:

What should be:

> 2020-10-26 14:49:06.391  INFO 1228 --- [0.0-8082-exec-4] main.api.Main
> : Main.healthCheck

What writes to file:

> [2m2020-10-26 14:49:06.495[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11612[0;39m
> [2m---[0;39m [2m[0.0-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36m    [0;39m
> [2m:[0;39m healthCheck

Comment: Those are ansi escape characters to set the color.  Tell the culprit code not to do that.

Comment: Also don’t write a logging framework yourself. Java has one built in.

Comment: As @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen said, unless there's a strong reason, please fallback to standard logging library, slf4j for log4j or logback.